# Unable to create pipe using cefclient

Tags: c++, pipe, chromium-embedded

I'm using cefclient in my application pretty much as is, except for the entry point (`cefclient_win.cc`).
I start it up and a browser window shows up but nothing gets loaded in it.
After a while the refresh button is enabled, but clicking it does nothing as well.

In the log file I get this:

```
[0714/170658:WARNING:ipc_channel_win.cc(276)] Unable to create pipe "\\.\pipe\chrome.5432.0.197852861" in client mode: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[0714/170713:WARNING:ipc_mojo_bootstrap.cc(214)] Detected error on Mojo bootstrap channel.
[0714/170713:WARNING:channel.cc(130)] WriteMessage() while shutting down
[0714/170714:WARNING:ipc_channel_win.cc(276)] Unable to create pipe "\\.\pipe\chrome.5432.1.123441216" in client mode: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[0714/170730:ERROR:process_win.cc(134)] Unable to terminate process: Access is denied. (0x5)
[0714/170730:WARNING:ipc_channel_win.cc(276)] Unable to create pipe "\\.\pipe\chrome.5432.2.118634471" in client mode: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[0714/170742:ERROR:process_win.cc(134)] Unable to terminate process: Access is denied. (0x5)
[0714/170742:WARNING:ipc_channel_win.cc(276)] Unable to create pipe "\\.\pipe\chrome.5432.3.396064" in client mode: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
```

Here's how I start the cefclient:

```
void MyCefApp::start() {
   this->browserHandler = new client::ClientAppBrowser();
   this->browserThread = boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyCefApp::run, this));
}

void MyCefApp::run() {
   CefMainArgs mainArgs(GetModuleHandle(nullptr));
   void* sandboxInfo = nullptr;

   #if defined(CEF_USE_SANDBOX)
      CefScopedSandboxInfo scopedSandbox;
      sandboxInfo = scopedSandbox.sandbox_info();
   #endif

   CefRefPtr<CefCommandLine> commandLine = CefCommandLine::CreateCommandLine();
   commandLine->InitFromString(::GetCommandLineW());

   scoped_ptr<client::MainContextImpl> context(new client::MainContextImpl(commandLine, true));

   CefSettings settings;
   CefString(&settings.resources_dir_path) = RESOURCES_DIR_PATH;
   CefString(&settings.locales_dir_path) = LOCALES_DIR_PATH;

   #if !defined(CEF_USE_SANDBOX)
      settings.no_sandbox = true;
   #endif

   context->PopulateSettings(&settings);

   scoped_ptr<client::MainMessageLoop> messageLoop;
   if (settings.multi_threaded_message_loop) {
      messageLoop.reset(new client::MainMessageLoopMultithreadedWin);
   } else {
      messageLoop.reset(new client::MainMessageLoopStd);
   }

   context->Initialize(mainArgs, settings, this->browserHandler, sandboxInfo);

   client::test_runner::RegisterSchemeHandlers();

   context->GetRootWindowManager()->CreateRootWindow(
      true,
      settings.windowless_rendering_enabled ? true : false,
      CefRect(), 
      std::string());

   int result = messageLoop->Run();

   context->Shutdown();

   messageLoop.reset();
   context.reset();
}
```

I run the application on windows (8.1) and not using the sandbox mode.
Any ideas as for what's happening here and why?
Thanks.

---

Edit

In my main function I check the process type:

```
if (MyCefApp::IsCefProcess()) {
   return MyCefApp::RunCefProcess();
}
```

If it's indeed a CEF process (meaning that it's not client::ClientApp::BrowserProcess) then I do:

```
int MyCefApp::RunCefProcess() {
   CefMainArgs mainArgs(GetModuleHandle(nullptr));
   void* sandboxInfo = nullptr;
   CefRefPtr<CefApp> handler;

   switch (GetProcessType()) {
      case client::ClientApp::RendererProcess:
         handler = new client::ClientAppRenderer();
         break;

      case client::ClientApp::OtherProcess:
         handler = new client::ClientAppOther();
         break;
   }

   return CefExecuteProcess(mainArgs, handler.get(), sandboxInfo);
}
```

Comment: try running with --single-process, that may change the behavior enough to give a better clue what the error is.  At least it's helped us find problems quicker in the past.

Comment: I can't seem to do that, cefclient crashes saying: `Cannot use V8 Proxy resolver in single process mode`.  From what I've found it was a bug but was supposed to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

That's a very different startup than the samples I've seen or what we use, but the main thing I don't see is a call to CefExecuteProcess();

CefExecuteProcess is necessary to launch the Renderer and other subprocesses.  Without these the pipes that the main browser is trying to contact won't exist.  Unless that is being called from one of your other functions your client won't work.

Comment: You're right, the call for `CefExecuteProcess` isn't part of that code. I edited my question with the code that handles other processes than the `client::ClientApp::BrowserProcess`

Comment: Also, why is this startup different? it's excatly as it's done (except for the `CefExecuteProcess` part) in the [cefclient_win.cc](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/master/tests/cefclient/cefclient_win.cc?at=master) file

Comment: At what point do you call `CefExecuteProcess`? It's hard to work out flow of your code from the snippets. Ideally you call `CefExecuteProcess` immediately in the `sub processes`. Do you see multiple instances of your application spawned? You can use the `--renderer-startup-dialog=1` command to display a message box for each `render` process that's spawned (typically you'd use this feature to attach a debugger), in your case it just verifies that they're loaded.

Comment: @NitzanTomer sorry, you are using a slightly newer version of CEF than I have, so it is a bit different.  To diagnose this I'd first ask, does the vanilla Cef Client sample run?  It is possible your branch isn't stable, I've never used master, I've only run from a release branch.